# SDL2 image - IMG_Init() returns 0, with IMG_GetError() being empty

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-image

I'm trying to load a `png` image with SDL2. However, even though the file exists and the renderer is created correctly, `IMG_LoadTexture` will only return a nullptr, for no apparent reason.

The function I'm using `IMG_LoadTexture` in looks like this, where `texture` is a `SDL_Texture*`:

```
void setTexture(const char* filePath) {
    // check if the specified file exists
    assert(utils::fileExists(filePath) && "Texture file does not exist!");

    // this should set the texture, but never succeeds
    texture = IMG_LoadTexture(Game::renderer, filePath);
    if (!texture) {
        // error handling, this is always true
    }
}
```

The assert passes, so the file was found. `filePath` looks something like `"assets/texture.png"`. The `Game::renderer` is set beforehand and looks like this:

```
static SDL_Renderer* renderer; // in header

renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0); // in implementation
if(renderer) {
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 100, 200, 255, 255);
} else {
// error handling and quit
}
```

However, despite `IMG_LoadTexture` not returning a proper `SDL_Texture*`, `IMG_GetError()` is simply empty, meaning

```
std::cout << IMG_GetError();
```

after calling `IMG_LoadTexture` does not output anything.

Seeing as I'm at a complete loss as to why this happens, I hope someone can help me here.

EDIT: As requested, here is a more complete, compilable version of the program that produces the same error.

I'm on Windows 10 Home 64-bit, using the 32-bit version of MingW-w64 to compile on C++17. My SDL2 version is 2.0.8, and my SDL2_image version is 2.0.3.

Here is the image I would like to load:
[image: player]

The image is contained inside a folder called `assets` in the original directory and the build directory. (I use CMake to remove the folder in the build directory pre-build and copy paste it post-build).

And here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

void quit(SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer) {
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    std::cout << "Quit Test." << std::endl;
}

int main(int argv, char** argc) {

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0) {
        std::cout << "SDL initialized" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize SDL" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    auto window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1280, 720, 0);
    if (window) {
        std::cout << "Window created." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create window." << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }

    auto initError = IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    if (initError == IMG_INIT_PNG) {
        std::cout << "SDL_image initialized" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize SDL_image" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Return value: " << initError << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Error flags: " << IMG_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 3;
    }

    auto renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    if (renderer) {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 100, 200, 255, 255);
        std::cout << "Renderer created." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create renderer." << std::endl;
        std::cerr << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 4;
    }

    auto texture = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "assets/player.png");
    if (!texture) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load texture!" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << IMG_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 5;
    }

    quit(window, renderer);

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
SDL initialized
Window created.
Failed to initialize SDL_image
Return value: 0
Error flags:

Process finished with exit code 3
```

Comment: Does IMG_LoadTexture works with a MVCE?

Comment: I find it to be much more likely that problem is in your output code, e.g. not putting `\n` into stdout. Or if you're on windows, you might not see anything you put into stdout at all (without special handling).

Comment: I thought this was a pretty solid MVCE, but no, reducing the code has not helped me get this to work.
@keltar I've tried a number of different print commands, none of them have yielded any result (including adding \n or std::endl, as well as string concatenation or using std::cerr instead)

Comment: @L.Kue my statement was more about can you get anything printed at all, not related to `SDL_image`. As for the MCVE part - it is neither compilable nor verifyable (which would require OS, toolchain, library versions, and your image file). Have you initialised SDL_image with PNG flag set? What return value `IMG_Init` gave you?

Comment: Well it clearly failed to initialise, and exited before even trying to load your PNG, but I can't imagine situation when it doesn't set error message (not that it required to - but the code of SDL_image is not that big). I recommend stepping through IMG_Init (probably even building debug libraries), but it is up to you; actual problem is most likely it being unable to load `libpng*.dll` becuause it isn't in system32 or executable's directory, or have wrong architecture (like 32bit dll but 64bit executable).